# Pandas: Search and return data frame that includes specific words in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of something like the following structure:

```
NDB_No  Shrt_Desc   Water_(g)   Energ_Kcal  Protein_(g) ...   
01001   BUTTER,WITH SALT    15,87   717 0,85  
01002   BUTTER,WHIPPED,W/ SALT  16,72   718 0,49  
...  
01004   CHEESE,BLUE 42,41   353 21,4    28,74  
01005   CHEESE,BRICK    41,11   371 23,24   29,68
```

I want to get a dataframe that includes only the rows where in the `Shrt_Desc` column has items that are in the list `to_be_found = [BUTTER, PASTA, ..etc]` but not `CHEESE`
The word to be found (in the list above) could be anywhere in the `Shrt_Desc`, not necessarily in the beginning, like `SALT` above.

How should I approach this?
Thanks!

Comment: To make it easier to help, could you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  You may get someone to answer your question anyway, but it will probably be a lot quicker if you follow the standard in the linked article.  It allows me to copy and paste your example into my environment and experiment.  That saves me time and makes the answer more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code resolves the issue (based on @piRSquared hint above).

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

food_info = pd.read_excel("ABBREV.xlsx")
dfi_1 = food_info


to_be_found = ['BUTTER', 'CHEESE', 'MILK', 'OIL', 'CORN', 'SALT', 'INF', 'PEPPER', 'PASTA', 'GLUTEN-FREE']
found = []
dfi_6 =  dfi_1.Shrt_Desc.str.split(',')
for row in dfi_6.iteritems():
    for x in to_be_found:
        if x in row[1]:
            found.append(x)

print(found)
print(len(found))

c = Counter(found)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would `split` the `'Shrt_Desc'` column by comma then see if 'CHEESE' is in each split list.  Use this a mask on the `DataFrame`

```
to_be_found = set(('SALT', 'BUTTER'))

mask = df.Shrt_Desc.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: to_be_found in x)

df[mask]
```

Looks like:

```
  NDB_No                 Shrt_Desc
0  01001          BUTTER,WITH SALT
1  01002  BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT
```

Comment: thank you, that will not make it, since as in the example above the `WITH SALT` case and other similar descriptions like:   `CRACKERS,GLUTEN-FREE,MULTI-SEEDED & MULTIGRAIN` exist.  Thats why I will use the list for ['BUTTER', 'PAST, 'GLUTEN']  Your lambda function can iterate over the previous list?

Comment: added the reference to `to_be_found` that should address the issue

Comment: the complete data set is in [link](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=25700)  (EXCEL file) if you would like to experiment.